# git log tag1 tag2 под WSL

Tags: git

использую WSL, набираю git log -7 дает 7 строк, набираю команду git log tag1 tag2 (где хэш первой и последней из 7 записей) выдает все. Использовал точки вместо пробела, длинные хэши, менял местами, все одно

Comment: `git log hash2..hash1` Впрочем непонятно зачем всё это.Чем вам `git log -7` не устраивает. А вообще читайте документацию https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_ranges

Comment: Если вы хотите получить только первый и только последний, то замените `git log` на `git show`. Также обратите внимание, что `tag` != `commit`, поэтому ваше замечание в скобках только вносит дополнительный конфуз.